# Meaning of "over them"

Tags: meaning, subcontinental-english

> I took out the reports. He pored over them.

In this sentence, what is the meaning of "over them"? I guess it would be "fully".

Answer (score 3):

The use of 'over' is related to the verb [to pore](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Pore):

> 1. To read or study carefully and attentively: *pored over the classified ads in search of a new job.*

Answer (score 2):

pore over  sth  phrasal verb

to look at and study something, usually a book or document, carefully

She spends her evenings poring over textbooks.
  He pored over the letter searching for clues about the writer.

Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary

Answer (score -3):

It means to cover thoroughly or completely. Think of spilling water it covers all.